# What is the 2nd param in indexOf(a,b) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand more about Javascript Array.indexOf function

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(array.indexOf(2)); //return 1
console.log(array.indexOf(2,3)); //returns 6
console.log(array.indexOf(2,10)) //returns -1
console.log(array.indexOf(4,4)); //returns 8
```

I know first param return the index of the number in the Array. What is the use of 2nd param and when do we use it?

Thanks

Comment: Google sometimes helps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: `indexOf(2,10)`. Starting at index 10, is the 2 found? No. So return `-1`.  Helps?

Comment: Would habe been faster to google than to write the question...

Comment: Say you're inventing the `indexOf` method. How would you represent numerically that there was no index found? Well, using `-1` since from `0` to `n` is actually a *"found"* index. Therefore `-1` represents *"not found"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is the value to be found.

The second parameter is the starting index.

So:

```
indexOf(2, 3)
```

Means find the first occurrence of 2 starting at index 3.

The [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) provided by @Roko shows some  useful examples of this with some additional detail.